# HTML File Input on Android Devices

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have a web app running that has a button to pick a file, which is then read in and displayed in a text area.

The file input is done in the same way as this demo from w3schools [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_accept). I have changed the `accept` tag to support the file that the app can open and display, so the new accept tag is

```
accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,text/rtf,text/html,text/plain,application/pdf"
```

This tag works on desktop, however if you run it on a Android (I have used a Samsung Galaxy Tab running 6.0.1 and a One Plus One running 6.0.1) the tag does not work, it filters out no files, how do I get the `accept` tag to work on android with this file list?

Comment: If anyone can answer this, do you know if it is possible to edit the file dialog box that opens with android e.g. remove links to one drive or dropbox which appear on the left hand side?